# Hold button down by mouse?

Tags: unity, gui

When I hold down a button by mouse for 5 seconds, print a message. How to do this ? I wrote this script but is not working. I don't know if there other methods.

```
Public float clock;
Public Button out;

public void quit_out_mouse() {
    clock = Time.time;
    if(Time.time - clock > 3.0f )       {
        Debug.Log (" gone !! ");
    }

   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the code of @virtouso would work : It's not frame independent and if you hold the button down for 2 seconds, release it, the timer will not reset

```
public float duration = 6 ;
private float timer = 0;
private bool waitingButtonUp = false ;

private void Update()
{
    // Use waiting button up if you don't want the function to be called every 6 seconds
    // but you want the user to release the mouse button before being able to call
    // the function after pressing the button again
    if( Input.GetMouseButton(0) && !waitingButtonUp )
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime ;
    }
    else // Do not forget to reset timer when the button is not pressed anymore
    {
        timer = 0 ;
        waitingButtonUp = false;
    }

    if( timer > duration )
    {
        DoSomething();
        waitingButtonUp = true ;
        timer = 0 ;
    }
}

private void DoSomething()
{

}
```

Comment: Yes, you right. I edited his code and solve it. Thank you Hellium for the new script.